# Is the double evaluation of measurable function still measurable?

Tags: integration, measure-theory

Asume I have a Borel-measurable function $f : \mathbb R^d \times \mathbb R^d \rightarrow \mathbb R, (x,y) \mapsto f(x,y)$. My seemingly simple question is: is the function $x \mapsto f(x, x)$ still measurable. In particular, if $f$ is also integrable, is the integral
$$ \int_{\mathbb R} f(x, x) \mathrm d x $$
well defined?

P.S.: I have the feeling, this somehow relates to the question of the measurability of the Set $\Delta = \{(x, x) : x \in \mathbb R^d\}$. Though i found the standard result to this question, I am not entirely sure which answer applies to $\mathbb R^d$ or at least to $\mathbb R$, since I am unsure whether $\operatorname{Bor}(\mathbb R)$ is separable or not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The function $x\mapsto f(x,x)$ is the composition $f\circ j$, where  $j:\Bbb R^d\to\Bbb R^d\times\Bbb R^d$ defined by $j(x):=(x,x)$. Observe that $j$ is continuous, hence Borel measurable.

Answer (score 0):

Borel measurable, yes.

The integral on the diagonal need not exist assuming only double integral exists.  Surely you can find a counterexample for that.

Comment: I didn't even come up with a reasoning, if its measurable. Hence I also have no clue about a counterexample.

My only intuition would be to find something in $L^1(\mathbb R\times \mathbb R)$ where the diagonal is not in $L^2(\mathbb R)$ or something like that.

Comment: Also can you give me some kind of argument or citation for this? Like this this answer is not really enlightening.